# .net core 3.1: 'IAsyncEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

I have a .net core 3.1 console app.

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetFilePathsFromRelativePathAsync(string relativePath)
```

If I call it:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<FileUpload>> GetFileUploadsAsync(string relativePath)
{
...
    var filePaths = await service.GetFilePathsFromRelativePathAsync(relativePath);
...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error CS1061  'IAsyncEnumerable' does not contain a definition
>   for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
await foreach(var filePath in service.GetFilePathsFromRelativePathAsync(relativePath))
{
    ....
}
```

An `IAsyncEnumerable` is used to return a stream of elements that can be processed individually. That's why the feature is actually called [async streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams), causing quite a bit of confusion

**Converting to Task< IEnumerable< FileUpload>>**

The best solution would be to *not* convert, but change the signature to `IEnumerable<FileUpload>` and return new `FileUpload` instances as soon as they're created :

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<FileUpload> GetFileUploadsAsync(string relativePath)
{
    await foreach(var filePath in service.GetFilePathsFromRelativePathAsync(relativePath))
    {
        var upload = new FileUpload(filePath);
        yield return upload;
    }
}
```

You can also gather all results, store them in a list and return them, eg with a `ToListAsync` extension method :

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ToListAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken=default)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    await foreach (var item in source.WithCancellation(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

The best code is code you don't write though. The [System.Linq.Async](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async) project provides LINQ operators for IAsyncEnumerable, including [ToList](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToList.cs), and can be found [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/).

The code is very simple but includes a few optimizations, like using `ValueTask` instead of `Task` and special treatment for data that comes from other operators like GroupBy and Reverse, that have to consume the entire `IAsyncEnumerable` before producing their output.

Comment: Ok thats interesting... Is there any way then to go from IAsyncEnumerable to Task<IEnumerable<>> without the foreach?

Comment: You can change your method to `IAsyncEnumerable<FileUpload>` instead, and `yield return` new FileUpload instances as soon as they're produced. Or you can use (or copy) the code in the [System.Linq.Async ToList](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToList.cs) operator to add each item to a list and return the list at the end

Comment: Please rename `from` to `to` in the first and second foreach loop samples.

Comment: @Deano you mean `in`?

Comment: Correct.  Doh!  Thanks mate.

Comment: @Deano thanks. I was probably experimenting with LINQ in LINQPad as I was writing that code and mixed up `from` and `in`