# IAsyncEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, iasyncenumerable

This code in .Net Core 3.1, C# 8:

```
 await  dB.GetListAsync<OrigineDB>();
```

results in this error :

> IAsyncEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

The answer provided here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148747/4180382 didn't help me much since my method contains a yield and a loop like in the example.

What changes should I make ? I don't want to return a List.

```
 async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetListAsync<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
            cn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(nameProcStock, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (parms != null)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in parms)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

            dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (dr.Read())
                yield return ConvertToObject<T>();
        }
```

Comment: IAsyncEnumerable should be used in a foreach loop, then you can await it

Comment: Ok, but how to change dr.Read() to be a foreach loop ? It returns a boolean.

Comment: How does `GetObjectListAsync<OrigineDB>` and `GetListAsync<T>` related to each other?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  Corrected  the typo

Comment: @CodeNotFound .net core 3.1

Comment: Please add the code which should consume the returned value of `GetListAsync` and explain in more detail how you want to consume the returned value and which return type the calling method should have

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a method returns an object of the type `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` you can not await it and in fact you don't have to. You can simply use it in a async foreach loop and use it's content in the body of the loop.

You can consume a `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` like this:

```cs
await foreach (var item in db.GetListAsync<OrigineDB>()) 
{
    // do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I wish to return an IEnumerable object, not having to loop through it...

Comment: @OleEHDufour Why though? Then the return type of you calling function would need to be `Task<IEnumerable<..>>` which would not be helpfull in regards to the calling-calling-methode since it only could continue after the whole _list_ was ready to enumerate